# Combining arduino leonardo code with water alarm code

Tags: led, arduino-leonardo

I need to create something for a school assignment, but I'm stuck at the moment.
I have one code, which makes the Arduino Leonardo press space button on my laptop, which works.

I have another code, that turns on the LED when 2 wires are put in water.

Now I want to combine them, but I have no success.

Hope someone will help me with this.

These are the codes:

**The keyboard code leonardo:**

```cpp
bool eenkeergeweest = false;

#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup()
{
    // make pin 2 an input and turn on the
    // pullup resistor so it goes high unless
    // connected to ground:
    pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    // initialize control over the keyboard:
    Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    // while (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    //   // do nothing until pin 2 goes low
    //   delay(500);
    //  }
    delay(1000);
    // new document:
    if (!eenkeergeweest) {
        eenkeergeweest = true;
        Keyboard.print(' ');
        delay(100);
        //Keyboard.releaseAll();
    }

    // wait for new window to open:
    delay(1000);
}
```

**The code for the water LED:**

```cpp
int out = 12;
int in = 4;

int rd;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(out, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    rd = digitalRead(in);
    if (rd == HIGH)
    {
        digitalWrite(out, HIGH);
        delay(100);
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(out, LOW);
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arduino IDE has a _KeyboardMessage_ example. Did you look at it?

Comment: I you only want the space to be pressed once, you could just place the code in `setup`. But it's unclear what you want the combined code to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help but Matt allready fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want them to work ? Do you want the spacebar pressed when there is a high signal read (when the light goes on)?

If you want the space bar press when it goes high this might work:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

bool eenkeergeweest = false;
int out = 12;
int in = 4;

void toggleKeyPress (const char& keypress)
{
    if (!eenkeergeweest) 
    {
        eenkeergeweest = true;
        Keyboard.print(' ');
        delay(100);
    }
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(out, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in, INPUT);

    // initialize control over the keyboard:
    Keyboard.begin();

}


void loop()
{
    const int rd = digitalRead(in);
    if (rd == HIGH)
    {
        toggleKeyPress(' ');
        digitalWrite(out, HIGH);
        // wait for new window to open:
        delay(1000);   
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(out, LOW);
    }
}
```